# Update Server for template

Tags: templates, update, module-params, one-click-updates

Is it possible to use update server for managing template updates?

I read [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Deploying_an_Update_Server) that template is not supported.

But is the article up-to-date? Because on that article there is also a line that states :

> client - Required for modules and **templates** as of 3.2.0.

Comment: Thank you @webchum it works! I've checked and it is documented but hard to find!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/4829)

Comment: @Farahmand I added this answer because no one commented before so at first sight was difficult to determine if the answer was good or not. Maybe I should have commented instead of posting an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the [article](https://docs.joomla.org/Deploying_an_Update_Server) is not up-to-date because update server is working properly with template.

Here's the code I use in the templateDetails.xml

```
<updateservers>
   <server type="extension" name="mytemplate" priority="1">http://www.domain.com/updates/template.xml</server>
</updateservers>
```

And this is the content of my http://www.domain.com/updates/template.xml

```
<updates>
    <update>
        <name>My Template</name>
        <description>My Template</description>
        <element>mytemplate</element>
        <type>template</type>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <infourl title="My template 1.2"><![CDATA[ My template update ]]></infourl>
        <downloads>
            <downloadurl type="full" format="zip">http://www.domain.com/updates/template.xml</downloadurl>
        </downloads>
        <maintainer>Me</maintainer>
        <maintainerurl>http://www.domain.com</maintainerurl>
        <targetplatform name="joomla" version="3.[12345]"/>
        <client>0</client>
        <client_id>0</client_id>
    </update>
</updates>
```

Comment: thanks for the info, however, why does your downloadurl node attribute format="zip" and the value is the xml file location? www.domain.com/updates/template.xml

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI for anyone else who may be running into problems when deploying an update server for a template, the `<client>` must be set to `site` or `administrator`.

Do **NOT** use `0` or `1` for the `<client>`